# Hand cursor on disabled JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcomponent, mouse-cursor

I have a `JTable` within a `JScrollPane` which is disabled using `enabled(false)`, however I would still like to change to the hand cursor on rollover. I have tried simply setting the cursor of the table manually:

```
table.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
```

And I have tried overriding the getCursor() method of JTable:

```
JTable table = new JTable(tableModel){
   @Override
   public Cursor getCursor() {
       return Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR); //DOESNT WORK
   }
};
```

However neither technique works. One approach which I have got to work is to add a `mouseMotionListener` to the whole table, the problem with this however is that in the actual application pressing a button residing in the table causes a 'JOptionpane' to be shown; if the user proceeds to move the cursor out of the table and close the 'JOptionPane' then bugs can occur. Surely a 'MouseMotionListener' is excessive..?

I have also looked into overriding the `setEnabled` method of `JTable` (and subsequently `Component`), however I am struggling to find out which code prevents the hand cursor being displayed. Any help would be much appreciated! code below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TableCursorTest {
    public TableCursorTest(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        String[] headers = {"Items"};
        Object[][] data = new Object[][]{{"item 1"},{"item 2"}};
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, headers);

        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        @Override
           public Cursor getCursor() {
                return Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR); //DOESNT WORK
           }
        };

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.setEnabled(false);
        table.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR)); //DOESNT WORK


        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.weightx = 0;
        constraints.weighty = 0;
        panel.add(scrollPane, constraints);

        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new TableCursorTest();
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:** Sorry, the question is lacking some information: The Table does not always fill the ScrollPane so setting the hand cursor of the scrollpane causes a hand cursor over lines rows which don't exist. If possible, the hand cursor should only appear over rows of the table.

Answer (score 3):

```
table.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR)); //DOESNT WORK
```

While..

```
scrollPane.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR)); //DOES WORK
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the response. Scrollpane.setCursor does change the handCursor successfully, however it changes the cursor for the entire pane. I only want the hand cursor over rows of the jtable which is not always as large enough to fill the table.

Comment: *"I only want the hand cursor over rows of the jtable.."*  Fussy, fussy.  ;)

Comment: Ha sorry! I also tried `scrollPane.getViewport().getComponent(0).setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));` but it doesn't have any affect.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to `disable editing`, you can override the `isCellEditable` method of the table model [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#isCellEditable(int,%20int))

Also, if you need to `disable row selection`, you can set the `rowSelectionAllowed` to `false`.

And you can add `mouseListener` to your table and override the `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` for custom cursors, like this

```
    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
        {
            table.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
        {
            table.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        }

    });
```

**A complete working example of yours:**

```
public class TableCursorTest
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    String[] headers = { "Items" };
    Object[][] data = new Object[][] { { "item 1" }, { "item 2" } };
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, headers)
    {
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
        {
            return false;
        };
    };

    public TableCursorTest()
    {
        final JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);

        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
            {
                table.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
            {
                table.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
            }

        });

        table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        // table.setEnabled(false);
        // scrollPane.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        // // DOESNT
        // WORK

        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.weightx = 0;
        constraints.weighty = 0;
        panel.add(scrollPane, constraints);

        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new TableCursorTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this example will work correctly (if the current class extends Jpanel) :

```
table.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter()
    {
           public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
           {
              int row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
              if (row > -1)
              {
                 // easiest way:
                  table.clearSelection();
                  table.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);
                  setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

              }
              else {
                  setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
              }
           }
        });
    table.getTableHeader().addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter()
    {
           public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
           {
               setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
           }
        });
```